# Having trouble with servlets

Tags: html, forms, jsp, servlets, netbeans

[flow of website http://imageshack.com/a/img661/8053/64Mqxv.gif](http://imageshack.com/a/img661/8053/64Mqxv.gif)

I currently have `index.html` --> LoginCtrl working just fine. If the username and password are wrong the code forwards back to the `index.html` page and if the username and password are correct then it forwards to `BuildRegistration.java`.

This is were I can't figure out how to handle the forwarding from servlet to servlet to build a web page with a form. I made a jsp page with the form on it and I can forward to that jsp just fine but the professor wants me to forward to a another servlet and have it build the web page and form.

I can't find any resources on servlet to servlet interactions so any help with a link or explanation would be much appreciated.

LoginCtrl servlet:

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    if (request.getParameter("userName").equals("schmitts") &&     
        request.getParameter("password").equals("pass")){
        request.getRequestDispatcher("BuildRegistration.java").forward(request, response);
    } else {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("index.html").forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you pass to `forward()` is the path (relative or absolute, within the same webapp) of a mapped resource.

If it's a JSP under `<webappRoot>/foo/bar`, then the path is `/foo/bar/theJsp.jsp`. If it's a servlet, it's the path it's mapped to, using the `servlet-mapping` element of the web.xml file, or the `@WebServlet` annotation. If your servlet is mapped to `/registration/build`, then that's the path you should pass to `forward()`.